# How to fetch the current Location in every 1 min of interval?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, gps, android-ndk

I have implemented the Demo to show the current lat-long of the User.
Now I am able to see the lat-long of the current Position.
but I want to Set it to to be displayed in every 1 min of interval.
The code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener lListener = new mylocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lListener);
    }

    private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "My current location:\nLatitude:"+location.getLatitude() + "\nLogitude:" + location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

So, What should I have to do to make it to display the current lat-long in every 1 min of interval?
I think I have to use the thread to implement it. How to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lListener);
```

The argument in the method signify - provider, time, distance and the location listener.

Therefore to request an update from the Location listener you need to set the second parameter to 1000*60, because the time is recorded in milliseconds.

Comment: You can also use an AlarmManager, set it in intervals of 1 minute and call this block of code every time the alarm fires.

Comment: its not going to work. perhaps it will work if the Location is updated. But i dont want it. I just want that even if the Location is same, It will be toast on the screen. I think thread is the best use for it. So will you please tell me the code for it ?

Comment: don't know why do you want to do that. it'll only kill your battery quickly. Using a thread will work but would complicate matters. anyways as i said you can use the AlarmManager to get that effect.
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: :I am not worry about the battery. If u have some of thread that will execute in every 1min then please give it to me.

Comment: new Thread(){ 
public void run(){ 
while(true){ 
call your location listener here try{Thread.sleep(1000*60)}catch(Exception ex){}}}}.start();
just remember to show a Toast inside the runOnUiThread() block

Comment: I am Little week in thread. so Please give me more information. What is that mean to remember to show a Toast inside the runOnUiThread() block ??