# How to create a timer and background service who make call to a get location()(latitude and longitude) after every 5 min

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fetch the Current Location in Every 1 min of Interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592569/how-to-fetch-the-current-location-in-every-1-min-of-interval)

iam creted on working location class and another sendsms class

now I need to create background service with the help of timer to send sms current location after every 5 min

Comment: Please, don't just post a link to another question.  You should delete this.

Comment: Just a link to another question? How "Not a real question" can you get?

Comment: Barmar and brad help meto come out of this

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you do some research on your problem. Its very simple to get solution for such an easy question.

And don't ask same question multiple times

[How to get location after every 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640967/how-to-get-location-after-every-5-minute).

Anyway still if you are unable to find it out, I could help my level best

Just you have following ways to do this,

1. Through Background running `Service`.

   - Create a `Service` that registers `Location Listener`.
   - Create an `alarm` , when `Service` get called and set your `alarm time frequency`.
   - Create a `Broadcast Receiver` for receive your `alarm intent`.
   - After fetching location `unregister` your `Location Listener`.
   - When you feel , no need to fetch location then stop the `Service`.

Sample codes  will be very lengthy, So You can get easily examples for following in web,

- Creating a `Service`
- Create an `alramIntent` and `register` for `BroadCast Receiver`
- Create a `BroadCast Receiver` and `register` it with an `alarm Action.`
- Implementing `Location Listener`.

  2. Through `Timer` with `Runnable Thread`,
- Create a `Timer`.
- `Schedule` the `Timer` with `TimerTask` `run` method. You can schedule initial start time duration and periodic interval call time delay too.
- Invoke `Runnable interface` when scheduled time occurs.
- Make sure the `Runnable Interface` runs on `UI Thread` by `this.runOnUIThread(your_runnable_interface)`
- In `Runnable run()` method, register your `LocationListener` for updates
- And do `unregiste`r in `onLocationChanged()` after processed your new `location.`
- When you feel , no need to `receive location` then `cancel` the `Timer`.

Here is an example for `Timer` using,

```
//Declared Globally in class
Timer timer;
//Timer follows here

timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
@Override
public void run() {
callRunnableMethod();
}
},Set your initial start time, Set your time delay for interval);



//callRunnableMethod() goes here


private void callRunnableMethod()
{
//This method is called directly by the timer
//and runs in the same thread as the timer.
//We call the method that will work with the UI
//through the runOnUiThread method.

context or this .runOnUiThread(Location_Runnable);
}


//Location_Runnable goes here

private Runnable Location_Runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               
//Do something to the UI thread here

Just start calling or request for updates with your location listener here.
}
};


//Once you decided to stop the periodic location fetching then do cancel your timer,

timer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the LocationListener and request position updates as detailed here to get location updates. I think you need a context to do that but I hope this tutorial on location updates will help.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: iam allready did this code to get location latidude and longitude and also convert it in address also @@ now i wanted to maintain5minutes gap in beetween every location chANGE REPLY